# What perl module would be best to draw a graph in perl, for the data given below

Tags: perl, parsing, graph

```
42      kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       8a699fe62751d158dad57f6b9a3ae5a4        1291836592      4.1938788890839
4       kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       ca0317343500ac35d46ca6b6bfe5918d        1291836592      4.224240064621
38      kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       2a473f02e814896af9d20ad333dfd5c5        1291836592      4.2302849292755
9       kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       ac3942ad87fb0ce3efb034cdfc3d4c79        1291836592      4.2612450122833
31      kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       3497d90401e18483119b60a378bd8d27        1291836592      4.3139219284058
25      kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       377b12a86f6bbde33dc89e94cacd5246        1291836592      27.90621805191
3       kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       493bf2ba361b77d09305a14e9253322d        1291836592      29.722389936447
16      kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       4da5ab1f006a2cc591510a35c06ae129        1291836592      186.4758849144
5       kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       cdb69a2ffa7178ccf9500c14c763e322        1291836592      213.70409798622
44      kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       d0090ea7a75c6dafcc1a7bef604711c9        1291836592      214.08736300468
17      kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       6068162699f06809436ecdf9a71adc20        1291836592      252.15900206566
32      kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       725c69f8b61803df3d9e5d1dad348083        1291836592      257.89507007599
23      kssotest.yakabod.net    activityViewer/index.html       b9a8556e8273a29c7d5875b14ba7c845        1291836592      266.65344500542
```

5th column is the time since epoch, and 6th column is measured time in seconds.

Comment: i am trying out Chart::Clicker, it has some good examples, and has pretty straight forward API.

Comment: how can i store the values from 6th column into an array? any hints ?

Comment: In a loop split every line line and push whatever you want to an array (`@col6thvalues=(); while(<>) { @fields = split /\s+/; push @col6thvalues, $fields[5]; }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Term::Gnuplot`, `Chart::Graph::Gnuplot`, or simply just gnuplot without any perl

Comment: could not install it on my Macbook Pro, but seems to be working on ubuntu